# C++ Namespace is undeclared

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and am trying to learn OpenGL. However, when I try to compile my program, I cannot refer to a namespace that I have already created in my header file. The code is as follows:

engine.hpp:

```
#ifndef ENGINE_HPP
#define ENGINE_HPP
// ...
namespace render {
  void Initialise();
  namespace inits {
    bool glfw_init = false,
    glfw_window_init = false,
    gl_init = false;
  }
}
#endif
```

engine.cpp:

```
#include "engine.hpp"
// ...
namespace render {
  void Initialise() {
    if (glfwInit() == GLFW_FALSE)
    inits::glfw_init = false;
  }
}
```

O
I'm not sure why this isn't compiling. I'm using MinGW (GCC) on Windows 10 (64-bit).

My compiler message is:

```
error: 'inits' has not been declared
```

**Edit: Thank you everybody for your suggestions. It appears that although this was a compiler fluke (after my first edit, since others could not reproduce the issue and a reinstall fixed the issue), it is a symptom of a larger organisational problem within my code. Since I have only invested ~15 minutes into the program, I would prefer to completely rewrite this after learning more about the language. For now, I have created a class and solved the issue discussed. I'm a beginner, and any book/resource recommendations would be welcome!**

Comment: Are you aware that your code will make any compilation unit (source file) that `#include "engine.hpp"` emit another `render::inits::glfw_init` (and hence cause errors at linking/loading)? This whole thing smells like a very poor (attempt at) C++. In C++, data/methords like `init` or `Initialise()` are typically unnecessary and replaced by constructors.

Comment: Could not reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37fd43340f5a8ba5 Create a [mcve].

Comment: While taking into account, your edits: cannot reproduce. Are you compiling your code with G++?

Comment: Your edit corrected the code. I suggest to close.

Comment: @Walter The inits enum is supposed to store which parts of the program have or have not run. I completely forgot about constructors, and I would probably solve a lot of my problems this way. My code is at http://pastebin.com/cKuLCyap and http://pastebin.com/4VMy6EuE so that you can see the entire files.

Comment: Re: "The inits enum" - there is no `inits` enum. There is an `inits` namespace that defines three boolean variables.

Comment: @AlexV-P Why do you need to know which parts of the program have run? There should be no global connection of objects. Make objects know exactly the objects that they should. By the calls that happen in your main. You might want to create a question like "This is my project architecture: ... What can be improved?"

Comment: @Aziuth That would be a better question, I admit. I have followed the advice of Walter and others, and moved the Initialise() into a class. Since it was a 10 minute project using the few skills I have learned, I will read up on C++ and should be able to change the architecture of my program.

Comment: @AlexV-P Reading is good, but make sure to present your code to some people. Have them tear it apart. That's how one learns. With coding in some higher language, there is always space for improvement. Have that regularly with my code. Harsh but constructive criticism is the best criticism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not what you think it does.

```
// file engine.hpp
namespace render {
  void Initialise();
  namespace inits {
    bool glfw_init = false,     // these variables will be emitted with
    glfw_window_init = false,   // every source file that
    gl_init = false;            // #include "engine.hpp"
  }
}
```

will lead to errors ("mulitply defined symbols") at linking/loading. To avoid that you may declare the variables `extern` or use functions for setting/getting the state (stored in a variable defined in `engine.cpp`).

Comment: I've moved the whole Initialise method into a constructor and somehow I've avoided the issue. The example should compile, so I moved it into a different project and the issue persisted. I reinstalled MinGW and the problem was fixed.

Comment: Instead of global variables and construct function, consider making a class.

Answer (score 1):

You're using nested namespaces, so should be:

`render::inits::glfw_init = false;`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that Initialise() is in the render namespace.